# NGINX auth provider with granular control

Tags: docker, authentication, nginx, keycloak, nginx-reverse-proxy

I'm looking for a suggestion on what combinations of identity providers to use.

I want to authenticate LDAP users based on the groups they are members of.

Example:

- `secret1.example.com` can be accessed only by members of group A
- `secret2.example.com` can be accessed only by members of group B

Both subdomains are configured as proxy_pass on one NGINX instance. I've looked into a vouch!/keycloak combo but vouch! creates a cookie for the whole domain (`example.com`) which doesn't provide that granular control. There is a workaround with multiple vouch! instances and whitelists but that doesn't seem like a clean and easily servicable solution.

Ideally this solution sould be as granular as the auth_basic function in NGINX, but I'm not sure something like that exists.

Does anyone have some suggestions as to how to go about it?
Is NGINX the right solution for the job?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

To anyone who is encountering a similar problem, take a look at [Authelia](https://www.authelia.com). The setup documentation is pretty straight forward. While I haven't tried it yet it seems to satisfy my needs.